# IBM Worlight 6.0 - Distributing applications using Application Center

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

In the IBM Worklight 6.0 Information Center website it is written that *Distributing mobile applications with Application Center* is a new feature that is added. But it was there in v5.0.6 as well.

I just want to confirm whether there are any new features added or removed in this version?

Comment: Do we need to guess what you are reading? Link, please.

Comment: [version 6 infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html) In tutorials and samples section  here under 10. Moving to production category it is given **Distributing mobile applications with Application Center**  is newly added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "New" wording simply denotes this is a newly created IBM Worklight Getting Started **training module**, as opposed to having it only in the IBM Worklight Information Center.

Distributing applications with the IBM Worklight Application Center is obviously not new.
The component was simply enhanced in v6.0.

You can read about What's New at:

- [Improved serviceability](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/what_s_new/c_wn_serviceability.html)